# Temperature sensor for Linux

Tags: sensor, temperature, linux

I'm looking for a temperature sensor, that can be connected to a computer over an interface that is ubiquitous, like USB. I'd like to read the temperature data over the command line.

Any suggestions what I could use?

All I plan to do, is measure the ambient temperature in the vicinity of the computer, for instance 2m above it.

I can access internal sensors with `sensors`, of the `lm_sensors` package. If possible, I'd like a similar interface.

Comment: You probably wont find a "sensors" like command for what you are looking for, you may be able to write a quick script that will poll your USB/I2C adapter or serial port and print it to the CLI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be an i2c temperature sensor along with a USB to i2c adapter.
Plenty of different devices are [listed as supported](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices).

http://www.harbaum.org/till/i2c_tiny_usb/index.shtml

Comment: Exactly (and more) what I was looking for. I have experience programming micro controllers. This is the best solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Consider getting a [TI Launchpad](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_%28MSP-EXP430G2%29). TI is selling them cheap and one of the micros comes with a built-in temperature sensor. It comes with a board with USB and you can load a firmware that will send the temperature value to the computer.

Comment: The launchpad is targeted at $4.30, if you buy from sparkfun it is $5 and change.  You can buy several for the cost of an arduino, or one for the fraction of the cost of an arduino.  Dallas, now maxim, used to have a serial to one wire dongle for next to nothing that you could use with their one wire temp sensors, I imagine they have an alternate solution or here again just use an msp430.

Comment: I actually have two of those launchpads. I didn't do much with it, but for that thermometer thing, I'd rather use a tiny adapter directly connected to USB.

Answer (score 3):

This is the one we got for monitoring server room temperature with nagios and cacti: http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-digital-thermometer-dongle-software-displays-temperature-7003 (but from a different supplier).

There is an article in linux journal with some software to interface with it using perl to read the temperature, I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Does it run under Linux?

Comment: Nevermind, just found the post about the Linux driver.

Comment: I was able to get it up and running on a debian server in about 5 minutes.

Comment: This is exactly what I used (sensor off ebay though) to monitor server room temp on a linux box.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino is great for this, and it will give you a chance to learn the basics of microconrollers.

Looks like the launchpad is a pretty good alternative but the launchpad is not as friendly to beginners as the arduino.

Comment: Sounds like overkill though when you can get a USB thermal sensor unit on ebay dirt cheap (is there an echo in here!?)

Comment: I do program microcontrollers. I just need a solution, that would fit in with `lm_sensors`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a solder iron, these might be of some interest:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-sensors/yocto-temperature

http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=6

Answer (score 0):

Use an Arduino to have lots of flexibility on the sensor end.

Comment: Sounds like overkill though when you can get a USB thermal sensor unit on ebay dirt cheap